# WS2803 12V Strip Controller

Tags: led, power, heat, ws2811

I have made a circuit that is meant to control 12V LED Strips using a WS2803 Chip. 
The problem I am having is that the L7805CV regulator reaches 80°C while the 1k resistor bank reaches 40-50°C.

Because of the nature of the WS2803 chip being a current sink this is the only combination of parts I could find that would work to switch LED Strips.

The circuit: each channel has a 1k pull up that has a transistor connected to it, that transistor feeds a 390ohm pullup that goes to a final transistor that works with the LED Strips. All pullups go to a 5V line provided by the regulator from 12V.

[image: Full Circuit]

[image: k]

Comment: There is a circuit editor built in to the site.  Edit your question and press CTRL + M to open the schematic editor.  Or, make a screenshot of your schematic and insert it as a picture in your question.

Comment: Updated thanks didn't see it on mobile version!

Comment: 1st problem, 12VDC down to 5VDC is dropping 7V across the 7805. What current ? I would hazard a guess at a minimum it needs a heatsink, if it doesn't have one already.

Comment: I measured the current to the circuit at 0.31A @12V. Heatsink wise i have no idea which to get and how big.

Comment: You realize that your current through the 7805 is basically the parallel resistance of 18 390 Ohm resistors and 18 1000 Ohm resistors?  I figure around 16 Ohms.  Thats 300mA.  With the 7805 dropping 7 volts, it is having to pass 2Watts of power.

Comment: JRE, what would be the best solution to this? I have to make 100 of these units for a project.

Comment: I have extra regulators so im ok with adding a second one in parallel to the first to help with the load. I just thought that them being rated at 1.5A would be more than enough for this

Comment: Well, your measurement matches my calculations!

Comment: They are rated for 1.5A.  They need to be connected to a heat sink, though if you are going to use them like you want to.  They "waste" the voltage difference between input and output as heat.  The higher the difference, the higher the waste.  The higher the current, the higher the waste.

Comment: What heatsink would you recommend?

Comment: First question is:  Why this arrangement?  You are inverting the WS2803 output, then inverting it again.  The heat you are seeing in just in the inverting logic.  That's nuts.

Comment: Why aren't you just providing the LEDs with like 15V, and letting the WS2803 drive the LED strings?  It'll regulate the output voltage so the set current flows through the LEDs.  No fiddling with transistors needed.  The WS2803 can supply upto 30mA per output.  You can adjust it with a simple resistor.

Comment: Yah but LED Strips draw way more than 30ma. More like 60-100ma.

Comment: If you must use external transistors, then you really need a better way to do this job.  [Try using a current mirror.](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/31626/current-multiplier-divider-for-current-measurement)  There's tips in there on how to make a multiplying current mirror.  So, the WS2803 could be set for 1 mA, and the current mirror multiplies by 10 for an output current of 10mA to the LEDs.

Comment: The WS2803 regulates the current.  So, the LED strips won't be able to draw that 60-100mA.  See if they are bright enough at lower current and save yourself all of the mess.

Comment: Try driving just one of the strings straight from the 2803.  It might be bright enough, then you can just install some jumpers on your boards and be done.  Adjust the current and remove all the other channels first, of course.

Comment: That linked heatsink is what I meant.  If you have space for it and can mount it so that it doesn't pull the legs off the 7805, that is.  They make smaller/lighter ones as well.

Comment: And it would make sure the thing doesn't die right? Im using this for a huge 1800 channel fixture so if it dies mid event id have huge problems.

Comment: Could i add a series resistor to make the voltage drop on the regulator smaller?

Comment: Then the resistor gets hot.

Comment: Acording to another answer i found about these regulators it seems that if i add a heatsink it will only reach 50-60°C which seems ok?

Comment: @Mike Why don't you use a 7805 DC to DC drop in compatible regulator? The efficiencies are in the 90%+ range so you wont burn up all that power.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just replace the linear (aka power hungry) 7805 with a RECOM switching version of the 7805: -

[image]

[**Here's**](http://www.recom-power.com/pdf/Innoline/R-78Bxx-1.0_L.pdf) the data sheet.

Comment: Just looked it up and it costs $23 a peice. I need 100 of these and it would cost more than the whole project is worth.

Comment: You can get them cheaper - £4.50 in digikey in the quantity you need: http://www.digikey.co.uk/product-detail/en/recom-power/R-785.0-0.5/945-1037-ND/2256217

Comment: Certainly easier than trying to fix 100 boards.

Comment: To get cost down even more you could design a little PCB that just mounted a buck regulator i.e. a cheap one from TI that fitted the space envelope of the 7805 - try searching on ebay for a really small 12V to 5V buck regulator capable of the 300 mA you need. Here's a bit of a start: https://www.elektormagazine.com/labs/switched-7805-replacement-1202121

Comment: @mike better alternative,  any number of 12 to 5 volt car usb adapters. At a dollar or less retail.  Ditch the 7805

Comment: @Passerby thats actually a great idea!  Do those have switched regulators?

Comment: Now a days, yes. The ""1 Amp"" ones have a MC34063 switching regulator,  limited to 700~750 mA.  See https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Generic+1A+USB+Car+Charger+Teardown/10108

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your 12V LED strips manage the current themselves, then this should do the job and be much simpler besides - and doesn't need that overworked 7805.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJPFqi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You'll need to see if you need R1, and if so how big to make.  Probably 10K would do to make sure the LEDs turn off when the WS2803 says "off."

Set the current from the WS2803 down to 1mA.  That'll keep you from destroying the transistor.

The 2N3906 is good up to 40VDC, and 200mA.  For 12V and 100mA it ought to work OK.

Comment: Sorry if a stupid question but how would i set it to 1ma? Also i have the current circuit PCB made with 100 boards. How would I use them as they are now possibly?

Comment: See the data sheet.  The 2803 has a pin called IADJ - current adjust.  The resistor you connect from there to ground sets the maximum current for the outputs.

Comment: I have looked over it many times and have in the end went with trial and error because i could not understand the method they used to calculate the resistance.

Comment: You might get lucky and be able to bodge the pnp transistor in place of one of the npn ones.  Easier if you are using standard parts instead of surface mount.

Comment: Post a picture of the layout, maybe it'll be straight forward to mash it together.

Comment: The formula is pretty clear.  I=(1.25V/R)*22

Comment: Updated the pictures. New user so cant post more than 3

Comment: So, R=22/(1.25I)  Where R in Ohms and I in Amperes

Comment: Ohh yah I couldnt figure out what Vrext was. Thank you! Would setting it to a lower current with the current setup fix the heating issue?

Comment: Lower current wouldn't change the heating issue.  That's all in the 1K and 390 Ohm resistors.  You might improve that by changing the 1K and 390 for higher values.

Comment: Also just to add, i already have 4000 transistors, resistors etc. So if I could somehow fix it without throwing all that out it would be awesome.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that something (and probably lots of somethings) are going to have to be replaced to make this work.  You could put heatsinks on all the 7805s and just live with it.  Search your parts supplies for TO-220 heatsinks.  They make lots of them intended for that kind of thing.

Comment: Nobody will ever accuse you of lacking in self confidence.  All parts and boards for 100 units bought and built without having tested a prototype first.

Comment: I had a prototype that had minor heating of the resistor banks but i thought this to be normal as 40-50°C is ok. But didnt expect the Regulator to become a stove

Comment: Accidentally added answer instead of comment

Answer (score 0):

Update: I slapped a medium heatsink on the regulator and although the heatsink reaches about 70-75°C it has been running all night and is still chugging along today. Its bot the best way to do it but with a "warning hot surface" label I think I can get away with it. Thanks for everyone's input!

Comment: I hope your power supply is up to the task.  18 channels at 300mA=5A just for the driver section, then you also have to provide power to the 18 strings of LEDs, so another 1.8A or 2A at 12V. So, total 7A at 12V

Comment: When the system is running ive only seen .31A being drawn by the system. Where do you see 300ma per channel?

Comment: Brain fart.  Not 300mA per channel.  300 mA for each of the 100 of these things you assemble.

Comment: Oh yah i have 7 10A industrial suplies + 9 2A ones. This is spread out so technically i should be fine. I may get more suplies if needed. The system total is meant to draw close to a 1000W at peak consumption.